# Posts not being excluded in WordPress rest api with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

Here is the query url I am using.

```
queryUrl = '/wp-json/mx/v1/posts?exclude=22906';
```

And here is the ajax function:

```
$.ajax({
        url: queryUrl,
        datatype: 'json'
        success: function(data, textStatus, request) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
```

The returned data will still output the post id 22906.

Comment: if possible then please use version 2 for API. Maybe exclude not supported by version 1

Comment: @Jaydp For some reason if I use the v2 it fails in the ajax call.

Comment: Better to solve AJAX error because version 1 not support this function and maybe it create issue in future as v1 has limited access

Answer (score 1):

You're using the [v1 WordPress API](http://wp-api.org/index-deprecated.html#posts_retrieve-posts) which doesn't support the exclude param.